# how to find a certain named import in vscode

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, file-search

for example I have a following line in some file in my project:

```
import { Button, Switch, message, notification } from 'antd';
```

and the following line in another file:

```
import { Table, notification } from 'antd';
```

How can I use VSCode search to find both of these files? and any other file which also has `notification` function import from `antd`, among other functions/components from antd library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import \{.*notification.*from 'antd';`